# How to send dynamic content as an attachment file in email?

Tags: 8, files, emails

Normally we send files as attachments in the email if they are stored in the file system.

```
$file->uri = 'sites/default/files/file_name.pdf'; // File path
$file->filename = 'file_name.pdf'; //File name
$file->filemime = 'application/pdf'; //File mime type
$params['attachments'][] = $file;
$mailManager->mail($module, $key, $to, $langcode, $params, NULL, $send);
```

But I have dynamically generated content.

```
$content = <?xml version="1.0"?>
<root><element>element value</element></root>
```

I want to send it as an XML file attachment in the email. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the answer.

Here is my code.

```
$content = '<?xml version="1.0"?><root><element>element value</element</root>';
$params['attachments'][] = [
  'filecontent' => $content,
  'filename' => 'data.xml',
  'filemime' => 'application/xml',
];
```

and then in hook_mail

```
function mymodule_mail($key, &$message, $params) {
  switch ($key) {
    case 'my_email_key':
      $message['body'][] = $params['body'];
      $message['subject'] = $params['subject'];
      $message['params']['attachments'] = $params['attachments'];
      break;
  }
}
```

BTW I am using the [swift mailer](https://www.drupal.org/project/swiftmailer) module.

Hope this helps someone.